# Why is react adding comment blocks to my title tag?

Tags: reactjs

Why is react adding comment blocks to my text?

**My code:**

```
import React from "react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";

import express from "express";
const app = express();
app.listen(8080);

class MyPage extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>Hello {this.props.name || "UNKNOWN"}</title>
                </head>
            </html>
        );
    }
}

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send(renderToString(<MyPage />)));
```

**Rendered HTML with an comment block:**

```
<html data-reactroot="">
<head>
<title>Hello <!-- -->UNKNOWN</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT #1:** So far it seems that the only place that this happens is the `<title>` tag.

"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.": Yeah, I know. But there isn't anything else to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an || (or) logic operator without an actual logic, so (I think, maybe I'm wrong) react renders both this.props.name and the UNKNOWN string. Why it renders it as a comment, I don't know.

I would try something like:

```
<head>
      <title>Hello {this.props.name !== null ? this.props.name : "UNKNOWN"}</title>
</head>
```

Edit: In the following link is posted a workaround for the "issue" and the reason of it:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14725

> This is by design and helps React hydrate those text nodes correctly.

Comment: The || (or) operator usage is correct 'this.props.name' is undefined and therefore the value will fallback to "UNKNOWN". The issue is that react is adding "<!-- -->" also.

Comment: Maybe this could work, one comment on here posted a workaround for the issue: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14725